# How to sequence the xml tag values based on the transition between different complex elements and create sorted String array using java

Tags: java

I have below xml code with lot of transition complex elements

**Input.xml**

```
<MyTransf>
    <transition>
        <from>Start</from>
        <to>ReadFile</to>
        <quantity>45</quantity>
        <price>6789</price>
    </transition>
    <transition>
        <from>Mapper</from>
        <to>End</to>
        <quantity>43</quantity>
        <price>31313</price>
    </transition>
    <transition>
        <from>ParseXML</from>
        <to>Mapper</to>
        <quantity>23</quantity>
        <price>635342</price>
    </transition>
    <transition>
        <from>ReadFile</from>
        <to>ParseXML</to>
        <quantity>78</quantity>
        <price>32432424</price>
    </transition>
</MyTransf>
```

In each transition element I have from and to tag which denotes the transition of activity.

(Example)
In the first complex element I have **Start** value in the ***from*** tag then its flowing to **ReadFile** in the same complex element ***to*** tag then its flowing to **ParseXML** in the 4th complex Element then its flowing to **Mapper** in the 3rd complex element then flowing to **End** in the 2nd Complex element. Here I am trying to create a java code by reading xml and outputting final expected value in String Array in the below manner.

**Expected Output :**

```
StringArrayList = { "Start", "ReadFile", "ParseXML", "Mapper", "End" }
```

I have asked chatGPT it gives the below code. But its not giving expected output. Any help would we widely appreciated.

```
public class XMLSequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("transitions.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList transitionList = doc.getElementsByTagName("transition");

            String currentTransition = "Start";

            while (!currentTransition.equals("End")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < transitionList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element transition = (Element) transitionList.item(i);
                    String from = transition.getElementsByTagName("from").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String to = transition.getElementsByTagName("to").item(0).getTextContent();

                    if (from.equals(currentTransition)) {
                        System.out.println("Transition from " + from + " to " + to);
                        currentTransition = to;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying got this **working solution**. Its not a cleaner approach but it made it working

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("/Users/nithish/project/transition.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList transitionList = doc.getElementsByTagName("transition");
            ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

           // String from="Start";
           // String to = "";
            String temp="";

            for (int i = 0; i < transitionList.getLength(); i++) {

                Element transition = (Element) transitionList.item(i);
                String from = transition.getElementsByTagName("from").item(0).getTextContent();
                String to = transition.getElementsByTagName("to").item(0).getTextContent();
            //    System.out.println("inside i loop "+i+" ; from value: "+from+" ; to value :"+to);
                if(i==0)
                { from = "Start";}
                for (int j = 0; j < transitionList.getLength(); j++) {
                    Element transition1 = (Element) transitionList.item(j);
                    String from1 = transition1.getElementsByTagName("from").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String to1 = transition1.getElementsByTagName("to").item(0).getTextContent();
            //        System.out.println("inside j loop "+j+" ; from value: "+from1+" ; to value :"+to1);

                    if (i == 0 && from1.equals(from)) {
           //             System.out.println("inside start loop ");
                        stringArrayList.add(from1);
                        temp = to1;
                        break;

                    } else if (i > 0 && from1.equals(temp)) {
        //                System.out.println("inside j loop  from1 :" + from1 + " temp  :" + temp + "j val" + j);
                        stringArrayList.add(from1);
                        temp = to1;
                        break;
                    } else {
          //              System.out.println("here else j " + j);
                        continue;
                    }

                }

                if(i== transitionList.getLength()-1)
                {
                    stringArrayList.add("End");
                }

            }

            System.out.println("StringArrayList = " + stringArrayList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```